# Access structure array whose index is stored in a string

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures

I want to get a value from a structure array by code, and I'll have the index stored in a string.

I've tried to run this code:

```
function M = getdata(matrix,field,varargin)
exp = [];
for i = 1:nargin-3
    exp = [exp num2str(varargin{i}) ','];
end
exp = [exp num2str(varargin{nargin-2})];
M = eval('matrix(exp).(Field)');
end
```

However, it fails.

For example, suppose I have a structure array with 2 fields, A and B. So, I could write

```
MyStruct(1,1).A
```

A possible use would be:

```
M = getdata(MyStruct,A,1,1)
```

and I want the program to do:

```
M = MyStruct(1,1).A
```

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: ...Why not just do `M = matrix(varargin{:}).(field)`?

Comment: Because I really want to use `getdata` with something like: `M = getdata(MyStruct,A,1,:)` and, if I use the expression you say, I only get one value, not a vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getfield` function:

```
M = getfield(MyStruct, {1,1} ,'A');
```

Or if you wanted, say, MyStruct(1,1).A(3).B:

```
M = getfield(MyStruct, {1,1}, 'A', {3},'B');
```

Comment: It fails when one of the indices is `:`.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you give, this will suffice:

```
function M = getdata(matrix,field,varargin)
    M = matrix(varargin{:}).(field);
```

which you call like

```
getdata(myStruct, 'A', 1,1)
```

which makes that function pretty useless.

But, in general, when you have indices given as strings, you can follow roughly the same approach:

```
%// Your indices
str = {'1', '2'};

%// convert to numbers
str = cellfun(@str2double, str, 'UniformOutput', false);

%// use them as indices into structure
M = myStruct(str{:}).(field)
```

And if you *really* insist, your call to `eval` is just wrong:

```
M = eval(['matrix(' exp ').(' field ')']);
```

And, as a general remark, please refrain from using `exp` as the name of a variable; it is also the name of a built-in function (the natural exponential function).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, none of the solutions given are useful for me. What I really want to do is using `:`as index. `cellfun` is also useless because the conversion from string to cell returns NaN.